# Solve mathematical function in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, math

I have created this function for a shopping basket. To be simple, i have x products with (2 checkbox + quantity input) for each.
The first checkbox add +3, second +8, to the product price. It's like (3+8+price)*quantity. At the end of the page, i have the total result (like product1 + product2...Etc)

The problem is: If i'm posting the form with new quantities, and going back to the page, **i have the default result (total price)** (of course, checkbox are checked + new quantity with PHP).

Here is my function:

```
$(function(){
    var item_prices = 0;
    var total_item_prices = 0;
    var total_unique_item_prices = 0;
    var total_price = 0;

    $.each($('*[data-item-price]'), function(index, element) {
        var item_price = $(element).data("item-price");
        total_unique_item_prices = parseInt($('[data-total]').html()) + item_price;
        total_price = total_unique_item_prices;
        $('[data-total]').html(total_unique_item_prices);
    })

    $.each($('*[data-item-price]'), function(index, element) {

        var item_price = $(element).data("item-price");
        var price_of_options = 0;
        var quantity = parseInt($(element).find('input[data-quantity]').val());

        $.each($(element).children().find("[data-price]"), function(index, element2) {
            $(element2).click(function(){
                var actual_price = parseInt($('[data-total]').html());
                var actual_item_price = parseInt($(element).find('[data-item-total]').html());
                var price = $(element2).data("price");
                if ($(element2).is(':checkbox') && $(element2).is(':checked')) {
                    price_of_options += price;
                    $(element).find('[data-item-total]').html(actual_item_price + (price * quantity));
                    $('[data-total]').html(actual_price + (price * quantity));
                }
                else {
                    price_of_options -= price;
                    $(element).find('[data-item-total]').html(actual_item_price - (price));
                    $('[data-total]').html(actual_price - (price * quantity));
                }
            })
        })

        $(element).find('input[data-quantity]').bind('keyup mouseup', function () {
            var new_quantity = parseInt($(element).find('input[data-quantity]').val());
            var quantity_dif = new_quantity - quantity;
            var actual_price = parseInt($('[data-total]').html());
            if (quantity_dif > 0) {
                quantity_dif = new_quantity - quantity;
                $(element).find('[data-item-total]').html((item_price + price_of_options) * new_quantity);
                $('[data-total]').html(actual_price + ((item_price + price_of_options) * quantity_dif));
            }
            else {
                quantity_dif *= -1;
                quantity = parseInt($(element).find('[data-quantity]').val());
                $(element).find('[data-item-total]').html((item_price + price_of_options) * new_quantity);
                $('[data-total]').html(actual_price - ((item_price + price_of_options) * quantity_dif));
            }
            quantity = parseInt($(element).find('[data-quantity]').val());
         })

    })
})
```

**As I said, code is working: https://jsfiddle.net/redbean/4dy38ye4/1/ Just not when i'm reloading the webpage.**

I'm not english, be kind about this. I'm trying to do the best to be clear!

Comment: What does this have to do with "Solv[ing a] mathematical function in javascript"?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is about mathematics, because we need to solve something about additions, substractions, multiplications. (Simple maths) Maybe i'm wrong.

Comment: Since you say that your code is working unless when navigation occurs (reloading, going back) I assume that browser caching or javascript initialization is the culprit here, not incorrect math.

Comment: 1. When you generate html don't forget set checked="checked" for elements to add; 2. Run calc funcion after display it (onload / ready); 3. this is very simple solving, but isin't problem

Comment: Not really about browser caching or Js init (don't think so), i'm really thinking about a math mistake. Probably incorrect maths because i have found a problem when you're spamming the checkbox (check Fiddle). Thanks for helping by the way ^-^

Comment: @bato3 checked="checked" is set/saved by PHP when i'm going back to the page.

Comment: @Kenley: but you dont run calc `price_of_option` on page load. js binds click, keyup, mouseup

Comment: Hello @bato3, thanks for helping. I have wrote that `$( document ).ready(function()` But no change, and about set check="checked can you use my JSfiddle [link]https://jsfiddle.net/redbean/4dy38ye4/2/ and say where you changed something? Thanks a lot man.